# Newbie question on long equations with regression output

Tags: statistics, economics

I'm confused as to the kind of math that economists due, specifically in their data analysis. Sometimes I see economists make really long, complex, seemingly novel equations and then--bang!--there's a regression table on the next page. The whole thing seems really disconnected. I understand multiple regression and lots of other types of regression models very well, but I don't even know what kind of subject to start looking into when I study these economics papers. It is econometrics? It seems much more abstract that traditional panel data stuff.

Ugh!

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's econometrics you need to study for the mathematics they use.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be rabbit holing down that then! Very new to this, much appreciated!